# Add image to orgchart shape using VSTO for Visio

Tags: .net, vsto, visio, organizational-chart

I am working on Implementation of dynamic organization chart.

In my project (in visual studio 2010 - winformapplication) i used VSTO for Visio (visio 2010).
Now I want to add an image to my shapes (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Shape) in OrgChart (orgch_m.vst) template.

Can anybody help me in this?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at John Goldsmith's solution for adding images to orgchart shapes.

http://visualsignals.typepad.co.uk/vislog/2008/06/linking-org-chart-images.html

Comment: Hi and thx for your answer but that is not my issue
plz give me a way to do this in my .net codes.